# Swift Orientation override for a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble to allow only 1 view controller in marking portrait,Landscape right and left, that view controller has a button to a video on youtube embed link I just want to allow rotation to this view,

I allowed all orientations in app and tried to add this to other view controllers that I wanted to be portrait but no chance

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue.hashValue | UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue.hashValue
}
```

is there anyother way to implement this I mean I will only allow portrait in general app setting but override one that  in the video view controller view,or just like first one I tried in general setting allow all orientations but allow only portrait in all views except videocontrollerview,  thanks advance for any help..

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no code I can't say for sure but you might be missing this in your view controller so that those supportedInterfaceOrientations can work:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```